# How to store multiple user entries

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to figure out how to store user specific data in Wordpress. The user is supposed to insert their weight, the date and then be able to make multiple entries so that each entry can be presented in a table for that specific user.

I was wondering if this is possible to do through a plugin like JetEngine? And would this be possible to do through meta data or would I have to use something like Custom Content Type?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two solutions for your problem.

**Easy solution**
Use a plugin like ACF with repeater add-on and create custom field for each kpi (weight, height, etc.) and for each add two sub field date and value.

**House made solution**
Create a json structure to be saved in the user meta which then decodes in php to show it in a table.

About this solution.

```
// The information return via $_POST
$weight=json_encode($_POST['weight']);
update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'weight',$weight)

// To show this information
$weight=json_decode(get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'weight',true);
// Create the table.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Lorenzo.
Would it be smartest to store the data through user meta fields or as a custom post type? 

The important thing is that the user is only able to view their own entries.

Comment: Shouldn't you sanitize your data? Why JSON encoding?